# Purple Hibiscus: The death of Eugene

Tags: character-analysis, chimamanda-ngozi-adichie, purple-hibiscus

How was Kambili affected by her father's death? I understand that she was the only one in the household who was able to love and see pass the image of a violent father but she was also physically and mentally abused. Also she was left to take care of her mother, who was overcome with guilt and with a her brother in jail. Was she at peace with his death? Was she not at peace with his death? What evidence would suggest either of these?

Comment: Could you please give a link to read the story/chapter/position of the story?

Comment: @AbhigyanC There is no specific link to post. I don't think there is an online copy of the novel.